# Does package manager remove dependencies when original package is removed?

Tags: apt, uninstall, dependencies

I am new to xubunutu and linux, my question is about how dependencies are removed from the system when we uninstall a package that caused them to install.

so consider this case that I install a package called test.

```
 apt-get install test
```

However this often gives a message saying following new packages will be installed as well. Assuming it installs 50 other packages as dependencies and continue to accept and install them.

Now later on I install other packages as well, assume if the newly installed packages use 10 out of those dependencies installed earlier.

I want to know when I remove the main package (test) in future using the command

```
apt-get remove test
```

Will it automatically workout 50 - 10 packages and remove them ?

or will it not remove any of the 50 packages ?

or will it remove all the 50 packages that were installed with test package?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I believe it depends on the package. Obviously, some dependencies are also dependencies for other packages, so those will stay installed.

However, if you run `sudo apt-get remove test` or `sudo apt-get purge test`, then it will let you know that there are a bunch of dependencies that can be removed (albeit manually via `sudo apt-get autoremove`) if there are any dependencies that *only* that package relied on.

Now, I don't have a super credible source (no Debian or Ubuntu documentation) currently (searching now.) But, what I do have is what I get in the terminal when I try to remove a package (`shutter`) in my case:

[image]

Obviously, there would be a bunch of dependencies left over that would have to be manually removed.

From the [man page for apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/apt-get.8.html):

> autoremove
>
> > autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
> >     installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no
> >     longer needed.

Hope this helped! I'll look for a more credible source just to augment my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To remove package test from your system, you would run:

```
sudo apt-get remove test
```

To remove package test and its configuration files from your system, you would run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge remove test
```

Or you could use [synaptic package manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) to the same